# Policy error while adding organization dynamically through NodeSDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I am trying to add organization dynamically to the channel through NodeSDK. I have followed the below steps:
- Extract channel configuration which returns in the protobuffer
- Convert it into json so as to read it
- Modify the json
- Encode it into proto buffer
- Calling the updateChannel method of library

All the steps are executed successfully but while calling the updateChannel method, it gives me policy error.
Please find below the logs of orderer:

> 2019-02-20 13:28:28.470 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU a2f ==
>   Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/Org1MSP/Admins
>   == 2019-02-20 13:28:28.470 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU a30 0xc0002afd50 gate 1550669308470922609 evaluation starts 2019-02-20
>   13:28:28.470 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU a31 0xc0002afd50 signed by 0
>   principal evaluation starts (used [false]) 2019-02-20 13:28:28.470 UTC
>   [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU a32 0xc0002afd50 processing identity 0 with
>   bytes of a0af20 2019-02-20 13:28:28.470 UTC [msp]
>   satisfiesPrincipalInternalPreV13 -> DEBU a33 Checking if identity
>   satisfies ADMIN role for Org1MSP 2019-02-20 13:28:28.470 UTC
>   [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU a34 0xc0002afd50 principal matched by
>   identity 0 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC [msp.identity] Verify -> DEBU
>   a35 Verify: digest = 00000000 b7 4c c6 c7 b4 e4 45 34 00 61 4b 80 51
>   3d 96 07 |.L....E4.aK.Q=..| 00000010 3f 6f 28 73 99 44 01 d4 44 8a 84
>   70 27 06 e5 08 |?o(s.D..D..p'...| 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC
>   [msp.identity] Verify -> DEBU a36 Verify: sig = 00000000 30 44 02 20
>   24 a7 07 ba c9 d7 4b 0d 60 95 eb c1 |0D. $.....K.`...| 00000010 96 d5
>   43 eb 3c fa 95 4f ce 44 2e 24 cd 2b d6 9b |..C.<..O.D.$.+..| 00000020
>   51 81 a6 cd 02 20 1f aa 81 d9 d7 d5 64 b4 36 54 |Q.... ......d.6T|
>   00000030 cf 6b 4b d7 eb 42 51 b3 43 cf 07 99 18 3d 97 6d
>   |.kK..BQ.C....=.m| 00000040 31 97 94 07 70 c0 |1...p.| 2019-02-20
>   13:28:28.471 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU a37 0xc0002afd50 principal
>   evaluation succeeds for identity 0 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC
>   [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU a38 0xc0002afd50 gate 1550669308470922609
>   evaluation succeeds 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC [policies] Evaluate ->
>   DEBU a39 Signature set satisfies policy
>   /Channel/Application/Org1MSP/Admins 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC
>   [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU a3a == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy
>   Policy /Channel/Application/Org1MSP/Admins 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC
>   [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU a3b == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy
>   /Channel/Application/Org2MSP/Admins == 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC
>   [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU a3c 0xc00047c690 gate 1550669308471165309
>   evaluation starts 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU
>   a3d 0xc00047c690 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used
>   [false]) 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU a3e
>   0xc00047c690 processing identity 0 with bytes of a0af20 2019-02-20
>   13:28:28.471 UTC [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU a3f 0xc00047c690 identity 0
>   does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different
>   MSP (expected Org2MSP, got Org1MSP) 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC
>   [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU a40 0xc00047c690 principal evaluation fails
>   2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU a41 0xc00047c690
>   gate 1550669308471165309 evaluation fails 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC
>   [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU a42 Signature set did not satisfy policy
>   /Channel/Application/Org2MSP/Admins 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC
>   [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU a43 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy
>   Policy /Channel/Application/Org2MSP/Admins 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC
>   [policies] func1 -> DEBU a44 Evaluation Failed: Only 1 policies were
>   satisfied, but needed 2 of [ Org1MSP.Admins Org2MSP.Admins ]
>   2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU a45 Signature
>   set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/Admins 2019-02-20
>   13:28:28.471 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU a46 == Done Evaluating
>   *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/Admins 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage
>   -> WARN a47 [channel: mychannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 192.168.64.1:47666 because of error: error authorizing update:
>   error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group] /Channel/Application not
>   satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 2 sub-policies,
>   required 1 remaining 2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC
>   [orderer.common.server] func1 -> DEBU a48 Closing Broadcast stream
>   2019-02-20 13:28:28.471 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO a49 streaming
>   call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-02-20T13:28:28.469Z",
>   "grpc.service": "orderer.AtomicBroadcast", "grpc.method": "Broadcast",
>   "grpc.peer_address": "192.168.64.1:47666", "grpc.code": "OK",
>   "grpc.call_duration": "2.221942ms"} 2019-02-20 13:28:30.655 UTC [grpc]
>   infof -> DEBU a4a transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection
>   error: desc = "transport is closing"

Kindly help me out what is missing in my configuration..........

Answer (score 0):

At the end when documentation says, **Sign and Submit the Config Update**
You need  org3_update_in_envelope.pb file to be signed by org2 also.

So , set environment variable for org2 like this:

```
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org2MSP"

export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt

export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp

export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
```

and run this command again for org2

```
peer channel signconfigtx -f org3_update_in_envelope.pb
```